# Creating a Class but function has its argument passed as ref Class array

Tags: c#-4.0

Here is code
I have a class like this,

```
public partial class Property
{

private string keyField;

private object valueField;

/// <remarks/>    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
public string key
{
get
{
return this.keyField;
}
set
{
this.keyField = value;
}
}

/// <remarks/>            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
public object value
{
get
{
return this.valueField;
}
set
{
this.valueField = value;
}
}
}
```

and a function is declared like this with two arguments

```
public VerifyRetailO VerifyRetail(ref Property[] Properties, VerifyRetailI VerifyRetailRq)
```

but i have difficulty in assigning the first parameter value , dont know how should i pass i.
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaration

```
Property[]classarr=newProperty[10];
for(inti=0;i<classarr.Length;i++)
{
//initialization
classarr[i]=newProperty();
}
```

or

```
Property[] oprop = new Property[1];
oprop[0] = new Property();
oprop[0].key = "D_Key";
oprop[0].value = "D_Value";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include the ref keyword in your method call:

```
Property[] Properties = new....//Instantiate first param or get it from somwhere
VerifyRetailI VerifyRetailRq = new..//Instantiate second param or get it from somwhere
VerifyRetail(ref Properties, VerifyRetailRq);
```

Comment: hi oscar i have initialized as Property[] oProp = new Property[0]; but i am unable to access properties present inside the class as [ oProp.key ]